# android 4.2.2 out of space

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, installation, insufficient-memory

My nexus4 2G RAM and 16G ROM, android 4.2.2. Got the root privileges afte bought it last year.

The situation puzzled me these days. Each time I tried to install app from google play or somewhere esle.  **Out of space error** came out and suggested me *Free up some sapce and try again*,  *Cancel* or *Manage apps*.

In fact 8.9Gb is available, Apps(app data & media content) occupies 733m. And this **Out of space error** doesn't come out when I updating apps.

I did some seach, uninstalled some apps, cleared app cache(one by one), even entered **recovery mode** and cleared **dalvik cache**, but it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(from an Android 4.4.4 user)

I began to have this problem after installing the Xposed module "**XInstaller**". I uninstalled that module and everything went back to normal.

Important: It can get easy to confuse all of these X words. It wasn't "Xposed Installer" that was the issue. The issue was the module for Xposed called "**XInstaller**". This module lets you change some of Android's default app installation/uninstallation behaviors. For now, I'm leaving that module alone.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer is a factory reset and even that doesn't work as it is supposed to. Shows formatting but nothing is removed when you boot up again.

I imagine the problem comes from Google servers restoring everything.  I don't know how to get around that.